# why depth-first is better than breadth_first iin most cases?

Tags: elasticsearch-aggregation

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_preventing_combinatorial_explosions.html

> he memory requirement of a breadth-first aggregation is linear to the number of documents in each bucket prior to pruning. For many aggregations, the number of documents in each bucket is very large. Think of a histogram with monthly intervals: you might have thousands or hundreds of thousands of documents per bucket. This makes breadth-first a bad choice, and is why depth-first is the default.

in breadth-first aggregation will have manay documents , but in depth-first is also have the same number documents , why depth-first is better ?

Comment: Imho the document explains that quite well and your quote is just the conclusion of the whole article.

Comment: " The memory requirement of a breadth-first aggregation is linear to the number of documents in each bucket prior to pruning. " , that means depth-first is not  linear to the number of documents in each bucket ?